# Does Google App-Engine supports flash message?

Tags: google-app-engine, grails

I am using grails 1.1.1 in my application.Flash messages ,like student id created, of my application working fine in local,but when i am updating to app-engine in server flash messages are not working.

I think GAE doesnt support flashmessage from er action.
If there is any solution please reposnse.

Thnks billion

Comment: I would Tag this with a 'grails' tag, as this seems more to be a grails issue.

Comment: Why do you think GAE doesn't support flash messages?  What is the underlying technology or technique that GAE isn't supporting?  Javascript?  HTML?  AJAX?  Form posting?  Flash messages are not a standard web technology, they are a feature that grails offers.   How does grails implement flash messages?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem, even apply the workarounds suggested by other users, it doesn't work. End up, my solution to this issue is replace all flash.message to session.message and in GSP, I write the following code:

```
       <g:if test="${session.message}">
        <div class="message">${session.message}</div><% session.message = null %>
       </g:if>
```

The solution was tested in GAE production environment. I wish this is helpful to those developers still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your question is in regards to the flash.message staying persistent when deployed to app engine.  Here is a [grails-user mailing list thread](http://www.nabble.com/Google-App-Engine-plugin%2C-flash-scope-tt24397492.html#a24397492) discussing this same issue.  A JIRA issue was requested but never logged.  I would suggest you package up a sample project showing the issue and log the JIRA issue.